# Will seaborn.barplot take the matplotlib.pyplot variable without any arguments passed?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm getting started with machine learning and I've been looking at a machine learning algorithm lately. I've seen seaborn.barplot take plt.figure to display the graph without any argument. How is that possible?

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (7,7))
sns.barplot(x = 'quality',y = 'fixed acidity', data = wineData)
```

fig is not passed as an argument to `sns.barplot` but it shows the graph according to figsize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
data = np.random.normal(0, 1, 3)
# array([-1.18878589,  0.59627021,  1.59895721])
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 6))
sns.boxplot(x=data);
```

In order to change the figure size of the seaborn package use matplotlib.pyplot.figure

The seaborn function that draws a bar plot, use matplotlib.pyplot.figure with the figsize keyword

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer the question. So, if sns finds 'figsize' from matplotlib.pyplot.figure above it , it uses that size to draw the graph.

Comment: yes seaborn uses the matplotlib.pyplot.figure to resize the plot

Comment: So, how will this functionality of using keywords work ?

Comment: the matplotlib.pyplot is imported as plt so all the function related to the package will be accessed using the keyword 'plt'

Answer (score 0):

In the seaborn barplot code you find the following [two lines](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/222d54467685b96ec9fabb32a9b382e35c745b1f/seaborn/categorical.py#L3140-L3141):

```
if ax is None:
    ax = plt.gca()
```

This means, if no axes `ax` is provided by the user, the current axes from the current figure is taken. The current figure has been created by you with the given figure size. So seaborn plots its barplot to this figure.